# Dont go to the next then promise, until previous is done

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise, es6-promise

In my node server I have the following code, using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) to do the queries

```
query('select id from client where cat=12')          
        .then((result)=>{    
          details = result.results; 
          details.forEach(element => {
             user.getInfo(element.id)
             .then((result)=>{ 
              console.log('results are ',result) ;
              myArray.push(result);
                if(myArray.length == details.length){
                  return myArray;
                } 
             })
          });
        })
        .then((result)=>{            
          console.log('check',result) ;

//.......
```

The logic of this is

take some ids, and for each one, run a function that is in another file (`user.getInfo` part)
push every result of the function to an array (myArray)
if the length of myArray is equal to the length of details, that means that there are no elements left, so we can return to the next `then`

The problem is that the `user.getInfo` takes some time and I guess because of the `user.getInfo(element.id).then` it returns to the last then immediately and I see first `'check',undefined` and then I see `results are` with the results

I would like to have the `user.getInfo` wait for the results and go to the next then, only when it has data.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: use Promise.all instead of forEach? And it gives your an array of results, you don't even nee to push it to your own array

Comment: The return value of a function inside `forEach()` is ignored. Where do you expect `return myarray` to return the value to?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the first `.then()` function, so there's no argument to the second `.then()`

Comment: @Barmar If I got what you ask, I expect the `myArray` to return to the last `then` when `myArray` is full of data.

Comment: @Barmar How else can I check the `myArray` outside the `foreach`, so I can return to the last `then` ? I see no other way, I am stuck.

Comment: Put all your promises in an array, then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them.

Comment: @Colin Thanks for the suggestion, you where the first to say about promise.all, so feel free to convert your comment to an answer , so I can chose it as the right one. Thanks

Comment: @codebot It's fine. I'm happy to help.